# Design neural network and implement it on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have been trying to design neural network which can fit this polynomial function :

y = 2x^2 + 4x^3 + 5

and i did this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def dataset(show=True):
    X = np.arange(-25,25,0.1)
    y = 2*X**2 + 4*X**3 + 5 +  np.random.randn(500)*1000
    if show :
        plt.scatter(X,y)
        plt.show()
    return X,y

X,y = dataset()

X_scaled = X/max(X)
y_scaled = y/max(y)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=4)
X_4 = poly.fit_transform(X_scaled.reshape(-1,1))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[5])])
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='mean_squared_error')
tf_history = model.fit(X_4, y_scaled, epochs=200, verbose=True)

mse = tf_history.history['loss'][-1]
y_hat = model.predict(X_4)
```

The instruction said that use 1 input , 1 output and 1 hidden layer with 3 neurons.
How should i configure those ?

Answer (score 1):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

# hidden layer with 3 neurons
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))

# output layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))
```